# Undefined references when linking avrfix

Tags: c, gcc, avr, avr-gcc, atmega

I'm trying to use the [avrfix library](http://avrfix.sourceforge.net/) in a project with avr-gcc 4.9.2 targeting the atmega644.

I have linked avrfix as described on the readme, however I am always getting errors such as

```
/tmp/ccrUM5Bo.o: In function `imu_calc_gyro':
imu.c:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `lmullkD'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:35: recipe for target 'main.elf' failed
make: *** [main.elf] Error 1
```

My avr-gcc invocation is

```
avr-gcc -Wall -Os -fshort-enums -std=c11 -mmcu=$(C_DEVICE) -I$(CINCLUDE)-lavrfix -Wl,-Map=project.map,-L$(LIB_PATH) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ $^
```

I think that the linker is able to find the avrfix library, because if I mispell -lavrfix, then (and only then) the linker complains it cannot find the library.

If anyone has any ideas, I would really appreaciate them.

---

EDIT: SOLVED!

For anyone having the same problem, I ended up separating the compile stage from the linker stage following Jonathan Leffler and 
user3629249 suggestions.

Important excerpt from my Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Os -fshort-enums -std=gnu11 -mmcu=$(C_DEVICE) -I$(CINCLUDE) -I.
LDFLAGS = -Map=$(OBJDIR)/drone.map -L/usr/avr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/avr5/ -lavrfix -lc -lgcc -lm

main.elf: $(OBJS)
    avr-ld $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

However, I ended up using gcc fixed-point functions with `_Frac` and `_Accum` following Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggestion. For that, I had to recompile my avr-gcc with the `--enable-fixed-point` flag.

Comment: Since you're running higher than 4.8 you already have access to `_Fract` and `_Accum`. You should verify that you actually need an external library anymore.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That could work. Do you know how to enable _Accum in avr-gcc 4.9? I get "error: unknown type name '_Accum'" when trying using it. And I couldn't find much about it.

Comment: They come with GCC itself. You'll need to include `<stdfix.h>` in order to load the definitions.

Comment: Put the library (`-lavrfix`) in a separate argument (not combined with the `-I` option as shown in the question) and add it after the object files (`$^`), not before.

Comment: 1) place the -lavrfix parameter after the -L parameter.   2) strongly suggest separating the compile step from the link step, as the linker is very picky about the order of its' parameters and any library names have to be after any '-L' parameters. The linker only looks at libraries in the order of the parameters and if the object files are after the libraries, then there will be nothing to resolve when the library is read.  Separate steps (compile/line) will make debugging much easier.  BTW: all warnings should be enabled,  I.E. -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That indeed worked. Thank you! If you create an answer, I will accept it as correct.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Although I was able to link avrfix following JonathanLeffler suggestion, I ended up using gcc _Accum. However, I had to recompile avr-gcc with the flag --enable-fixed-point. Thanks!